# how to select values in a list from pandas datetime in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dates in string format like this:

```
dates=['2021-06-23','2021-06-22','2021-06-18']
```

I'm trying to gather data for a stock (cl=f//crude oil) using yfinance library. Here is the code uptil now:
I'm trying to return the data for dates in the dates(list).

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

key='cl=f'

dates=['2021-06-23','2021-06-22','2021-06-18','2021-06-17']

data=yf.Ticker(key).history(period='max')
data['date']=data.index
data.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
#rearranging columns
cols=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Dividends', 'Stock Splits','date']
cols=cols[-1:]+cols[:-1]
data=data[cols]
print(data.head())
```

I've tried using:

```
data=data[(str(data['date'])== i for i in dates)]
```

It gave me the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([False, False, False, False], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Why am I getting this error?
Some assistance required.

Comment: Try `data[data['date'].astype(str).isin(dates)]`, Make sure doing `astype(str)` has the values in the same format that in `dates` list. I just tested it and it works fine. You don't even need `astype(str)` because the columns are already as string.

Comment: @Don'tAccept Thanks! this helped , I tried changing each of the value in the 'date' column to string earlier but it still didnt help, thanks!

Comment: `data = data[data['date'].isin(dates)]` astype str is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data = data[data["date"].isin(dates)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data=data['date'].astype(str).isin(dates)
```

worked. Answered by- @Don'tAccept (1st comment)

Comment: You forgot to do `data[condition]`. You only have `condition` right now. Also `astype(str)` is not needed.